# How many episodes of Little lord have been aired so far in Turkey?

Tags: little-lord

I see a dubbed Turkish series called [Little Lord](http://www.newstechcafe.com/2016/09/little-lord-serial-on-zindagi-tv-wiki.html). I probably have seen something like 40-50 episodes till date. I tried to find more info. about the series, like looking it up on [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3776084/) but as can be seen there is negligible information about the series. Can somebody share some more information as IMDb just shows 3 episodes, whereas in reality I have seen more than 40. Looking forward to know.

Answer (score 1):

There have been 71 episodes aired till 23 Dec 2016. While IMDb lists a few, you can find the complete list of episodes [here](http://www.ozee.com/shows/little-lord/episode-guide.html).

Though, I'm not sure whether your question is on-topic or not.

Comment: Actually I asked about it on meta and was told it's on-topic http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/where-do-television-series-fit-in

Comment: What you shared is till what I have seen today, didn't know had seen 71 episodes, so it's possible there may be more though, as the site you shared shows the dubbed ones, not the one in turkish. Thank you though for the effort.

Comment: I just checked your meta question . yes tv series is on topic here. However, your question is borderline as recommendations are off-topic for both TV and Movies. :-) .

Comment: @Panther I'm not asking for recommendations. I'm trying to know how many episodes of a TV series have been aired, not in India but in turkey. The answerer wasn't able to answer that, although he did help out in getting webisodes of the series.

Comment: @Panther it would have been a recommendation if I had asked if there was a similar series like 'Little Lord' that people could recommend. I fail to see how it comes anywhere near under recommendations ?

Comment: @shirish i got it that's why said it border line case of recommendation/listing. I just wanted to highlight buddy that being TV series quesion in ontopic as much as movie.